# Need to install new HDD in macbook pro, do not have installation disk, can this be done?

Tags: hard-drive, install

Bought a used Macbook Pro. Was working fine until I downloaded some contacts recovery software for iphone, it was useless so I uninstalled it. Since then machine has run   v e r y    s l o w l y......
I tried command r which took me into the reinstall but in Spanish! My technical spanish is not too good so I bailed out.
I have a 750gb hdd that will suit the machine, but I do not have original installation disks to install el capitan. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

Follow this:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372

Install the new internal HD.

Connect the installer drive and boot. It should automatically boot from the installer drive if it doesn't find a bootable OS X on the internal drive. If it doesn't, hold the Option key when you boot. It will boot into the OS X installer. You will figure it our from there.